# Trouble pushing to a Remote Git Repo located on Same Machine for Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am simply trying to set up a dummy local and remote repo and be able to push commits from my local repo to the remote repo. This is just practice, so both the local repo and remote repo exist on my local machine. I think the error is in setting up my remote repo. Below are the steps I went through:

1. Create the local copy of the app at ***`/Users/neil/Sites`***

   ```
   rails new someApp
   ```
2. I `cd` into ***`someApp`*** and then run `git init`.  Ok, now my local repo is created
3. Set up where my master branch pushes to: `git remote add origin '/Users/neil/Desktop/someApp` (origin doesn't exist yet, so I need to create it so master can actually push to origin).
4. Now to create that remote repo which master pushes to, which will live at ***`/Users/neil/Desktop`***.  This is where `origin` will be.  I created an empty directory with the same name as my local project: ***`someApp`*** and did `git init`

I make some changes to my local repo: `git add .`, then `git commit -m "xyz"`.  I am ready to push these changes to origin.  I do `git push -u origin master` and I get errors.

I attempted cloning the local copy and then pushing to the remote repo, but that didn't work either. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: *I get errors* -> which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to the fact that you're trying to push to a repository that is not a bare git repo.

If you want to push to an origin on the local disk, you need to init the repo you're trying to push to as `bare`

When you run `git init`, use `git init --bare` instead, then try to push.

Also, it's common convention to append the suffix `.git` to a bare repository that you plan to push/pull from.

So your proposed origin will be a directory called `/Users/neil/Desktop/someApp.git` and will initialized as a bare repo.

Comment: Thanks Ryan!  Thanks for also telling me about the .git convention.  I was curious about that.

Answer (score 1):

At step 4 you need to run `git init --bare` in order for you to be able to push to the repo.